# setup cuda , Cudnn nvcc version 11.8 in AWS ec2 Ububtu 22.04 instance

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, cuda, amazon-ec2

Trying to setup Cudnn with `nvcc --version` 11.8 in EC2 g4dn UBuntu 22.04 LTS with T4 GPU
setps followed .

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535`

`sudo reboot`

`sudo apt-get -y install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` (getting `nvcc --version 11.5` by default) required version `11.8`

`sudo apt-get -y install nvidia-cudnn`